# All About Exceptions: What to do and Where to log?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, exception

My question actually comes in two parts hence the ambiguous title.

**Part One**

As far as I'm aware, you should never swallow an exception. Not even logging it and forgetting about. In general cases, I try to solve an exception and retry the code - for example, let's say I get a FileNotFound exception.

I prompt the user to check the file exists and try again, offering another file chooser dialog and hoping for the best. Failing attempting to solve the problem I end up notifying the user and logging the exception. I've been told that this isn't the correct thing to do in a catch block, so am I doing it right by attempting to solve the issue?

I can't think what else I should do. I suspect I'm being fed misinformation - I'm a gullable soul.

**Part Two**

Creating a log in my program directory to log an exception is fine I think, but again I'm being told that exceptions should be written to the windows eventlog. Is this correct? Under what circumstances should you write to the event log?

Silly questions need silly answers.

Edit:
There is no context to this question other than a general vague domain. My friend and I were blabbering about the right things to do in particular circumstances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off if you ever hear the word **Never** your ears should perk up... That is why they are called "Best Practices" and not "Rules written in Stone that you must follow..."

here is Microsoft's [Exception Handling Best Practices Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts(VS.71).aspx)

And there are going to be plenty others...

It really boils down to you as a developer, your teams standards, your customer, etc. What do you want the application to do?

**Question 1:** Do you want the application to be able to continue on if an exception it thrown? Then I would "swallow" the exception.

**Question 2**: Is there a benefit to logging a particular exception to the event log or is it just going to bloat it with useless information, You may want to write every exception to the log during development and testing and have verbose information and then in production streamline it... I hope I have answered your question even though there really isn't an generic one...

I would say you should have some general guidelines and then if you have more **specific situations** then it would be a good time to re-post to this site and get some feedback from people that have tried different routes and can speak to the pros and cons.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it was mostly just a general conversation between myself and a friend with no real conclusion. I should probably add this to the question.

Comment: Then why did you post it here if it was just between you and your friend :0)

Comment: Because we ended up disagreeing and I figured I could ask the question to the wider audience to see who was closer to right (and it was him)

Answer (score 2):

The [Code Analysis Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/06/14/631923.aspx) is a great place to start on this topic. Also look at

[Martin Fowler - Fail Fast](http://www.martinfowler.com/ieeeSoftware/failFast.pdf)

[MSDN on Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229005.aspx)

[Checked vs Unchecked Exceptions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129)

The second part of your question really depends. In many applications where you need central exception reporting, writing to the event log is a good idea. There are plenty of other cases where it would be a waste of time to do that, you'll have to use your own judgment on that.

Answer (score 1):

**Part One**

Generally, you don't want to have exception generating behaviour in a catch block.

```
try
{
   ExceptionThrowingMethod();
}
Catch(Exception ex)
{
   //Log It
   //Try Again
   ExceptionThrowingMethod();
}
```

Clearly, the second exception will be uncaught, and you generally don't want to have try-catches nested *within a catch-block*.
 Generally your catch block should

1. Log the error. Always. Even if you set it to your lowest logging level, and never read those logs.
2. Determine whether your current state is recoverable. (Are the right variables set or null? Did it break during a critical function, or between them?)
3. If you can recover, set some variables that indicate 'try-again', and allow execution to flow OUT of the catch-block. If you cannot recover, try to add some context, and then re-throw the error.

Catch blocks are for error recovery, not for regular execution. So, even through FileNotFound is an exceptional occurrence, prompting the user to try and locate their file is *not*, and so it should happen in its own try-catch (or loop back to the initial one).

**Part Two**

Generally, I would prefer writing logs to their own directory, because that way I know exactly where they are, and I also know that everything in the log is relevant. If your application is a critical application, (I.E. a service that needs to be running for a framework to work) then you might consider logging to the eventviewer. There's also the everybody wins method of logging to both. You could have thorough logs in your program directory, and log any critical errors to your event viewer.

Without knowing what reason you were given to log to the event viewer, I can't tell whether or not it's good advice.

Comment: It was just a discussion really without any context. My friend and I concluded it was probably a context specific case but it would be better to write to the event log as, "that's why it's there".

Answer (score 0):

Here are some best-practices for exception handling.

[Best practices for exception management in Java or C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409563/best-practices-for-exception-management-in-java-or-c)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't believe that answers my question.

Comment: You asked for silly answers :) ... I agree, it doesn't completely answer your question, but it does address exception handling best-practices which is something you may want to research while you are investigating how to handle exceptions in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I'll give you credit there. I learned something new from that link but still failing to find answers. Never wasted!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238583/windows-exception-handling-to-event-log-or-to-database) to answer part two of my question and it seems from a bit of further research that logging exceptions to the event log isn't a mysterious and dark practice. Thanks for your help everyone.